# Find the incorrectness of the process.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Assume $$A\xi=\lambda_1\xi $$
then $$A\xi\xi^T=\lambda_1\xi\xi^T $$
and $$|A\xi\xi^T|=|\lambda_1\xi\xi^T| $$
which we will have 
$$|A|\cdot |\xi\xi^T|=\lambda_1^n\cdot|\xi\xi^T|$$
then $$|A|=\lambda_1^n$$
But $$|A|=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i$$

What's the problem in this process?

Comment: Writing $|A\xi\xi^T| = |A||\xi\xi^T|$ is incorrect. Here I am interpreting $|A|$ to mean $\sup\{Ax:\ |x|=1\}$.

Comment: @caffeinemachine In that case we wouldn't have $|A|=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i$. It's most likely meant as determinant.

Comment: Also, perhaps putting brackets would help avoid confusion. For instance, $A\xi\xi^T$ is $(A\xi)\xi^T$.

Comment: @Arthur I see. Thanks. Then $\det((A\xi)\xi^T) = \det(A)\det(\xi\xi^T) = \det(A)\xi\xi^T$ is also not correct. :)

Comment: @caffeinemachine Is also not claimed in the post. At least the last equality. The first equality you wrote is correct though.

Comment: @Arthur I was thinking $\xi\xi^T$ is just the dot product of $\xi$ with itself. I think I should get out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Take a good look at $|\xi\xi^T|$. Think about, say, the rank of that matrix and what that means for the determinant.

Comment: Tks. Its rank is less than n.

Comment: @JaqenChou So, either $n=1$, in which case ..., or $n\neq 1$, in which case ...